# How stop SSDP packets?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

Am watching my wifi interface card using wireshark and i'm noticing hundreds of SSDP packets with destination 239.255.255.250 and info 'NOTIFY'.

Any idea how to stop my computer from sending these packets? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must know which application is generatin this kind of trafic(SDP). [Here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Protocol-Analyzers-Sniffers/Process-And-Port-Analyzer.shtml) you can find one oftware that can sniff the process responsible for generating this trafic.

After that, you have two options to stop SDP trafic:

1. Install some [firewall](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=firewall&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:pt-BR:official&client=firefox-a) and configure it to block all SDP trafic.
2. Kill the process responsible for generating this trafic(if it isn't an essencial process.

Comment: I found another way, disable 'SSDP Discovery' in services under startup. Seems to be working...

Comment: Hmmm, in this case, where is a windows service that generate the trafic it is the best way to do it.... Just a comment, be aware that this service isn't indispensable for the good work of your system....